Prevent my QRCode from being copied to another medium (paper/card, screen.. etc)
I want to make an app that reads QR code from places that I and only I have generated the code for.
For example, I make a QR code and stick it to the wall and I read it normally, if other people have access to the QR code it should work (because it's my paper). But if someone takes the paper, puts it into the scanner (or used their phone) and reprints it, I don't want them being able to read it (because it's not my print)
Is there a way to stop the QR code from being reprinted? Like putting some code to it or using some kind of paper that loses its data when copied..

As a QR code simply encodes data and you're printing it to a static medium such as paper, this is a very hard problem to solve.
Imagine that rather than a QR code containing the words "https://example.com" you're printing it onto a piece of paper in normal English:

It's easily read by others
The original is easily duplicated
It's easily recreated (anyone can print a new document with "https://example.com" on it).

The same points apply to a QR code printed on paper. They're not magical, just a way to write words / URLs / arbitrary data.
You can't prevent problem 1. Even if you used special ink that confuses a copier machine, a photo will work just fine.
Bank notes mostly solve problem 2 by having a watermark that prevents most copiers, printers and scanners from duplicating them but printing your QR code on a bank note is probably not a great solution.
For problem 3: If you are writing a custom app, you could intentionally include errors in your QR code. The QR code scanner will compensate for these errors to return the correct original message, but you could reject attempts that don't include your intentional errors. It's similar in nature to how some CD-ROM copy protection used to work. This doesn't solve problem 2 and developing this will require quite a bit of knowledge of how QR codes are generated and read.

If you let go of your requirement to have the QR codes printed on paper, there are options. In some applications where it's desired that QR codes aren't copied, the generated code changes every few seconds. To do this, you will need:

To display the code on a display (LCD / eInk)
To accurately keep the time on this display
A secret value stored on the display

Your QR code will now contains something like "https://example.com?signature=...". The signature will consist of a hash of the message, the secret value & the current time—for example, date+hour+minute.
When you scan the QR code, you check if the signature matches. If the signature doesn't match, the code was tampered with or expired.
If you're publishing URLs in the QR codes, you can do this server-side so you wouldn't even need a custom scanner app for this. If you're publishing plain text, you can still do this, but you'd need to check for the signature in a custom app and reject codes that don't include a valid signature.
This will solve problem 2 (a duplicate is useless in a matter of seconds/minutes) and problem 3 (a recreated code won't have a valid signature).

After tons of research, I found a way, which is to print the QR code on a Security paper, they're cheap, can't be reprinted, and even if a photo is taken of them they can't be reprinted because they're affected by the light.. This is used by governments to check for original documents

That will allow you to detect copies, but how will that prevent copies?

I can make my own app and check if it's copied, if it is I will stop the transaction since the QR code is only useful inside of my app
